# Transition with new Material Design Support lib

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I've tried to make an animation from a Floating Action Button to a new activity like said in this page :

http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

In section: Activity + Fragment Transitions

But I don't see any transition on screen.
What is the problem???

In Original Activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/spg_rosa"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_add_pdv"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

In destination Activity, in mainLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/spg_azul"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_add_pdv"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

And the code:

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I added parameters to Intent() because it was giving me error
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddActivity.class);
            String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_add_pdv);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options =
                    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
                            fab,   // The view which starts the transition
                            transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
                    );
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), intent, options.toBundle());
        }
    });
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use `(Activity activity, View sharedElement, String sharedElementName)` you must enable the content transitions feature.

> This requires FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS to be enabled on the calling
>   Activity to cause an exit transition. The same must be in the called
>   Activity to get an entering transition.

To do this, set the feature **before** the setContentView(int) in the onCreate of *both* the exiting and entering Activities:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
}
```

Note: This feature is for API 21+. Although, there are some work arounds libraries I believe e.g. [github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere](http://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere)

Comment: still saying API 21+ :(

Comment: ok! Tx for your help! please update your answer, and I'll accept it